# Google SMS verification codes broken on a loop - should I be concerned?

Tags: authentication, google, authorization

So this is a little out of the ordinary. Not sure what to make of it.
I've enable **2-Step Verification** on a Google account.

When opening mail or other G-related services, it sends an **SMS(text message)** to my cell, with a code. That code is used to complete the login to mailbox... But obviously you already knew that !

A few weeks back, few minutes after a successful login, I received the same code again. Figured it was a cell provider glitch. Then again. And again the same code. So on for a day or so.. weird, but didn't think more of it, life goes on.

Except that now everytime loging in to Google, same happens, which is concerning.
I ruled out the phone itself as a cause (iPhone), it's in good health, recently restored to factory settings, and the glitch is only with codes from Google.

I've made an illustrated screenshot, with timestamps visible.. see for yourself :)

For clarity : while receiving the **SAME** code again i'm still logged in and experience no disruption on the web.

From the Google help :
`Note: If you received multiple verification codes, only the newest one will work. If you requested multiple verification codes, keep in mind that it might take some time for the latest code to arrive.`

Usually when you request a code again, it's supposed to send a new one, so doesn't look like someone is trying my account over and over again.

Any of you smarties have a clue what might be in play?

[image]

Comment: Sounds like you may want to contact support.

Comment: Sure, but before i do, wanted to rule out potential security holes that may not be related to google’s texting server, hence my post :)

Comment: It could be an issue with your network provider.  What happens if you do request a new code (open an incognito view?)

By the way, you should switch to an authentication app rather than SMS.  SMS is vulnerable to attacks, plus useless if you have no mobile signal.